# mysql wont start on Oracle Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I installed mysql following instructions on this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html) on my fresh installation of OEL 5. However when I try to start the mysql service with `service mysqld start` I keep getting

```
chown: `mysql:mysql': invalid user
chown: `mysql:mysql': invalid user
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

When I try to check user's information with `id mysql` I get user does not exist and when I try to add user, it says user already exists!

If I try to start mysql or ecen check its version for instance, I get:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -v
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Worst part is there is no mysql.sock file on my whole file system. I confirmed it by firing `find / -name mysql.sock` which returned empty result.
AM I missing some configuration step or something? I am absolutely clueless. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please, which of the corresponding linux distribution are you using ? have you try to run it in `sudo` mode: `sudo service mysqld start` ? To see if *mysql user* have been created run `cat /etc/passwd | grep 'mysql'` or `cat /etc/passwd`; normally; it special user for specific purpose (here mysql administration).

Comment: I am using Oracle Enterprise Linux. Also since I am running as root, I don't need sudo, However, I did try it as you suggested but to no effect. Same error

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | grep 'mysql' 
returns empty. Also no such other user as you have asked

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question @arsel

Comment: Ok! do the command `echo $PATH` have this path `/usr/sbin` in the result ?

Comment: if not try this : ```/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 89 mysql &>/dev/null &&
  /usr/sbin/useradd -u 89 -g mysql -d /var/lib/mysql -s /bin/false mysql &>/dev/null &&
  usr/bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr &&
  chown -R mysql:mysql var/lib/mysql &>/dev/null ```

Comment: I got the following output:
`[root@localhost ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
`

Comment: mysql runs under the user called `mysql`. If it is not in `/etc/passwd` you have to add it; the way you can do that is by using `useradd` command which is normally in `/usr/sbin` directory. So if you don't have this directory in your path variables environments you have to add it before install `msqlserver`. You can do that by doing `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin` or add the path to your `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` config file.

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question, I cannot add user. It already exists

Comment: It seems like that path already present in your $PATH variable environment ! have you try previous commands line ?

Comment: Sorry ! we have a delay in our messages

Comment: Try: `/usr/libexec/mysqld` and print here the result !

Comment: I get No such file or directory

Comment: It seems like your user `mysql` has been created in NIS database. You can make a verification by run: `ypcat group | grep mysql`. In this case, if your /etc/nsswitch include nis for passwd/group, you have to tell mysql to stop looking at NIS for user/group information. Maybe this topic can help you: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/175344-chown-mysql-mysql-invalid-user.html

Comment: Wooh! we will try to reinstall the server. Can’t you uninstall it and try to install it again? we will see what happen step by step!

Comment: Umm, already did. still will try again.. and let you know. I can't do so now, however will update you with the same